# undefined reference to `std::errc::operation_canceled` when compiling websocketpp example code with mingw

Tags: c++, c++11, websocket, boost-asio, mingw-w64

I'm trying to use `websocketpp` to write a cross-platform program that communicates using websockets. I would like to use the `asio`-based transport layer.

My understanding was that if I am using C++11, I can configure `asio` to stand-alone from boost and use `std::thread`, and that `websocketpp` is similarly header-only under such circumstances.

However, when I actually try to compile any of the `websocketpp` tutorials this way, such as the `tutorials/utility_client`, it works fine on g++ and clang, but I get strange compilation errors on mingw:

```
In file included from websocketpp-0.6.0/include/websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls_client.hpp:32:0,
                 from main.cpp:7:
websocketpp-0.6.0/include/websocketpp/transport/asio/endpoint.hpp: In member function ‘void websocketpp::transport::asio::endpoint<config>::handle_accept(websocketpp::transport::accept_handler, const error_code&)’:
websocketpp-0.6.0/include/websocketpp/transport/asio/endpoint.hpp:764:28: error: ‘operation_canceled’ is not a member of ‘std::errc’
             if (asio_ec == lib::asio::errc::operation_canceled) {
                            ^
```

I'm scratching my head as to what this means and how to fix this. This doesn't appear to be related to the lack of boost -- `std::errc::operation_canceled` appears to be a well-defined C++11 symbol according to [this, not always accurate, website](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errc). Does this mean my toolchain is broken / defective? I tried installing a different version of the mingw toolchain and it had the same problem.

I couldn't find any references to anyone having similar problems with this symbol not being found, so maybe I'm configuring the library wrong? Here is my compilation line:

```
"$CXX" -std=c++11 -Iasio-1.10.6/include -Iwebsocketpp-0.6.0/include -D_WEBSOCKETPP_CPP11_THREAD_=1 -DASIO_STANDALONE=1 main.cpp -lpthread
```

[I made a repository](https://github.com/cbeck88/wspp_mingw_test) to assist in reproducing my exact setup, but there's not much going on here -- I downloaded both libs from most recent releases from their respective repos. Since compilation dies in one of the includes the body of `main.cpp` seems not terribly relevant, but I am just using their tutorial code.

If anyone could throw me a line on this I would greatly appreciate it. :)

Edit: I am not really sure but I have reported this as a bug at mingw-w64:
http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/support-requests/105/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have reported this as a bug at mingw-w64

The mingw-w64 compiler is C++11 non-compliant in not defining this error-code,
but the folks already know that and it's deliberate. (Although offhand I don't
know why they *couldn't* fix it.)

The relevant header file is:

```
<toochain_dir>/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bits/error_constants.h
```

and here is the definition of `enum class std::errc`:

```
// Most of the commented-out error codes are socket-related and could be
// replaced by Winsock WSA-prefixed equivalents.
  enum class errc
    {
//    address_family_not_supported =        EAFNOSUPPORT,
//    address_in_use =              EADDRINUSE,
//    address_not_available =           EADDRNOTAVAIL,
//    already_connected =           EISCONN,
      argument_list_too_long =          E2BIG,
      argument_out_of_domain =          EDOM,
      bad_address =                 EFAULT,
      bad_file_descriptor =             EBADF,
//    bad_message =                 EBADMSG,
      broken_pipe =                 EPIPE,
//    connection_aborted =          ECONNABORTED,
//    connection_already_in_progress =      EALREADY,
//    connection_refused =          ECONNREFUSED,
//    connection_reset =            ECONNRESET,
//    cross_device_link =           EXDEV,
//    destination_address_required =        EDESTADDRREQ,
      device_or_resource_busy =         EBUSY,
      directory_not_empty =             ENOTEMPTY,
      executable_format_error =         ENOEXEC,
      file_exists =                     EEXIST,
      file_too_large =              EFBIG,
      filename_too_long =           ENAMETOOLONG,
      function_not_supported =          ENOSYS,
//    host_unreachable =            EHOSTUNREACH,
//    identifier_removed =          EIDRM,
      illegal_byte_sequence =           EILSEQ,
      inappropriate_io_control_operation =  ENOTTY,
      interrupted =                 EINTR,
      invalid_argument =            EINVAL,
      invalid_seek =                ESPIPE,
      io_error =                EIO,
      is_a_directory =              EISDIR,
//    message_size =                EMSGSIZE,
//    network_down =                ENETDOWN,
//    network_reset =               ENETRESET,
//    network_unreachable =             ENETUNREACH,
//    no_buffer_space =             ENOBUFS,
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_ECHILD
      no_child_process =            ECHILD,
#endif
//    no_link =                 ENOLINK,
      no_lock_available =           ENOLCK,
//    no_message_available =            ENODATA,
//    no_message =              ENOMSG,
//    no_protocol_option =          ENOPROTOOPT,
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_ENOSPC
      no_space_on_device =          ENOSPC,
#endif
//    no_stream_resources =             ENOSR,
      no_such_device_or_address =       ENXIO,
      no_such_device =              ENODEV,
      no_such_file_or_directory =       ENOENT,
      no_such_process =             ESRCH,
      not_a_directory =             ENOTDIR,
//    not_a_socket =                ENOTSOCK,
//    not_a_stream =                ENOSTR,
//    not_connected =               ENOTCONN,
      not_enough_memory =           ENOMEM,
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_ENOTSUP
      not_supported =               ENOTSUP,
#endif
//    operation_canceled =          ECANCELED,
//    operation_in_progress =           EINPROGRESS,
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_EPERM
      operation_not_permitted =         EPERM,
#endif
//    operation_not_supported =         EOPNOTSUPP,
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_EWOULDBLOCK
      operation_would_block =           EWOULDBLOCK,
#endif
//    owner_dead =              EOWNERDEAD,
      permission_denied =           EACCES,
//    protocol_error =              EPROTO,
//    protocol_not_supported =          EPROTONOSUPPORT,
      read_only_file_system =           EROFS,
      resource_deadlock_would_occur =       EDEADLK,
      resource_unavailable_try_again =      EAGAIN,
      result_out_of_range =             ERANGE,
//    state_not_recoverable =           ENOTRECOVERABLE,
//    stream_timeout =              ETIME,
//    text_file_busy =              ETXTBSY,
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_ETIMEDOUT
      timed_out =               ETIMEDOUT,
#endif
      too_many_files_open_in_system =       ENFILE,
      too_many_files_open =             EMFILE,
      too_many_links =              EMLINK
//    too_many_symbolic_link_levels =       ELOOP,
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_EOVERFLOW
    ,
      value_too_large =             EOVERFLOW
#endif
//    wrong_protocol_type =             EPROTOTYPE
   };
```

You see that `operation_canceled` is one of those commented out.

As suggested there, you will need to use the winsock error code `WSAECANCELLED`,
defined in `winerror.h`. If you want portability, of course you'll need to
make this use rather than `std::errc::operation_canceled` conditional upon compiletime determination of the host OS.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think you are right. I decided to try patching it a different way in my project, without trying to introduce new enum values, or make it dependent on platform defines. Instead I try to use SFINAE to detect if the needed enum value is missing. I made a PR to websocketpp visible here: https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/pull/479/files