# How to build LLVM 7.0 with MinGW?

Tags: c++, mingw

I am trying to build LLVM on Windows 7 with MinGW. I run CMake with this command

> C:\Users\Elidio\Desktop\llvm-7.0.0.src\build>cmake -G "MinGW
>   Makefiles" -D"CMAKE
>   _MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release  ..

it took some time configuring the makefiles, but when I started the build, eventually it throws me this error:

> [  1%] Building CXX object
>   lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/CachePruning.c pp.obj In file
>   included from
>   C:\Users\Elidio\Desktop\llvm-7.0.0.src\lib\Support\CachePr
>   uning.cpp:17:0:
>   C:/Users/Elidio/Desktop/llvm-7.0.0.src/include/llvm/Support/Errc.h:66:23:
>   error:  'not_supported' is not a member of 'std::errc'
>   not_supported = int(std::errc::not_supported),
>                          ^~~ lib\Support\CMakeFiles\LLVMSupport.dir\build.make:258: recipe for
>   target 'lib/Su pport/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/CachePruning.cpp.obj'
>   failed mingw32-make.exe[2]: ***
>   [lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/CachePruning.cp p.obj] Error 1
>   CMakeFiles\Makefile2:598: recipe for target
>   'lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport. dir/all' failed
>   mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/all]
>   Error 2 Makefile:150: recipe for target 'all' failed mingw32-make.exe:
>   *** [all] Error 2

What exactly must I do to compile LLVM with MinGW?

Comment: This seems like a mingw issue. Have you seen this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33662788/undefined-reference-to-stderrcoperation-canceled-when-compiling-websocketp) ?

Comment: `<toochain_dir>/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bits/error_constants.h`

Can you see how this file looks like for you? Is the `not_supported` enum member commented out also?

Comment: there are no such directory on my toolchain... i'm using mingw32... perhaps if I upgrade to 64 it will improve something

Comment: And I have seen that answer... the problem is that it suggest changes in the code, and since I am just building an mature project, I think it is not a good idea to fiddle with stable code...

Comment: Did you find any solution for the error? I m facing the same error and spent lot of time on that.